# JFrame on OS X with buffer strategy disables rounded corners

Tags: java, macos, swing, graphics, graphics2d

I'm trying to create a simple JFrame window in OS X and render a simple black square on it like so using Graphics2d:

```
public Start() { 
    running = true;
    window = new JFrame("Finest Hour");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    window.setSize(window.getPreferredSize());
    FullScreenUtilities.setWindowCanFullScreen(window, true);
    window.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = window.getBufferStrategy();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Start s = new Start();
    s.loop();
}

public void loop() {
    Random random = new Random();
    while(running) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
        strategy.show();
    }
}
```

However the window doesyn't seem to have rounded corners at the bottom when I use strategy.show(); :

[image: With strategy.show]

Rendering it without the buffer strategy, i.e: Graphics2D = (Graphics2D) window.getGraphics(); produces a window with rounded corners:

[image]

I know it's a really small problem but it's annoying none the less. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I recommend writing GUI related code in Swing's EDT: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: @SoboLAN it's actually for game animation, but I'm curious anyway to see the cause for this.

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me.

[image]

```
public class TestMacFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestMacFrame() throws HeadlessException {            
        super("Testing");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new PaintPane());            
        setVisible(true);
    }

    protected class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
            super.paintComponent(g);                
            int width = getWidth() - 1;
            int height = getHeight() - 1;                
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);                
            int blockWidth = width / 2;
            int blockHeight = height / 2;                
            int x = (width - blockWidth) / 2;
            int y = (height - blockHeight) / 2;                
            g.fillRect(x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight);                
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new TestMacFrame();            
    }
}
```

Now, I have no idea what it is you're trying to, but I can tell you this:

```
public void loop() {
    Random random = new Random();
    while(running) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
        strategy.show();
    }
}
```

Is a bad idea.  Firstly as SoboLAN pointed out, you're trying to update a UI component out side the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Swing components are not `Thread` safe.

Secondly, this loop will eventually chew up your CPU cycles, making you application unusable as well as you overall system.

**UPDATED with Animation**

Here, try this.  This is a really BASIC example ;)

```
public class TestMacFrame extends JFrame {

    private float angel = 0;
    private Timer timer;

    public TestMacFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Testing");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new PaintPane());
        setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                angel += 1;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    protected class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int width = getWidth() - 1;
            int height = getHeight() - 1;

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            int blockWidth = width / 2;
            int blockHeight = height / 2;

            int x = (width - blockWidth) / 2;
            int y = (height - blockHeight) / 2;

            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angel), width / 2, height / 2));
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight);
            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMacFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop was because I was planing to work with animations rather than a GUI, hence the buffer strategy and the setIgnoreRepaint();, but will it really be that bad on the CPU cycle? How should I be rendering it?

Comment: Try using a `java.swingx.Timer` instead, or take a look at one of the animation frame works, TimingFramework and Trident come to mind for `Swing`

Comment: @BubbaWoop I've added a REALLY BASIC animation example

Comment: So I just tried your original method and it resulted in square corners. However upon resizing (by dragging on the corner) I get rounded corners. Must be a problem with my java, time to update

Edit: I also managed to find the problem as to why my original window didn't have rounded corners was due to JFrame.setIgnoreRepaint

Comment: Edit 2: I also discovered that the real reason how the corners get squared is due to whenever the window or panel paints. If I force repaint() I get square corners again.